# How to link avatar and nickname to profile

Tags: author, links, avatar, profiles

On the single post page I want to link the avatar function to the author profile, but I tried

```
<a href="<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>">
<img src="<?php echo get_avatar($post->post_author, '64', $avatar); ?>">
</a>
```

but that doesn't work.

Also, how can I display the nickname (display name) and still link to the profile the following code gives a strange link and 404s

```
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(); ?>"><?php the_author_nickname(); ?></a>
```

some help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: First of all, `the_author_posts_link()` is a deprecated function since version 2.1, use `get_author_posts_url()` instead http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url; Second, make sure the code is not wrapped in a conditional `<?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) ) :` and your description is not filled; other conditions may apply, check your code and make sure the requirements are met. This is as far as I can go without knowing in what way is it not working? Errors? Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: `get_author_posts_url()` takes an argument that requires "ID of the author whose URL should be retrieved." http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url, that's the reason you're getting a 404, because the page "warning: Missing argument 1 for get_author_posts_url()" does not exist on your server, does it? :)

Comment: I tried get_author_posts_url(), it doesnt change anything. Yes, im getting a 'missing argument for get_author_post_url, basically i want the <?php the_author_nickname(); ?> code to link to the author url, im putting the code in the single post page

Comment: Supply the argument, Jack... `get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) )`, let me know if you problem is solved so that I can compile an answer to this question.

Comment: get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) is linking to the current page, not the author page. EDIT: added an echo, worked like a charm

Comment: this is the final code: <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>"><?php the_author_nickname(); ?></a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a short compilation of the multiple comments above, so that future visitors don't have to read each and every one of them.

First of all, `the_author_posts_link()` is a deprecated function since version 2.1, so `get_author_posts_url()` or `the_author_posts_url()` should be used instead http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url

The `the/get_author_posts_url()` takes an argument that requires "ID of the author whose URL should be retrieved.", so `the_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) )` will work, and if you decide to use the `get_author_post_url()` instead of `the_author_posts_url()` don't forget to echo it out.

Comment: Small correction - `the_author_posts_link()` is not deprecated, only passing arguments to it is deprecated